# how to know if user come from pwa not website

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I am working with PWA, there is a requirement: to statistics if users login from PWA or websites. There are no differences about the header. Do you have any ideas about this? thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell if the user is using an "Installed" PWA by checking for standalone in your script.
Then pass that check as an additional value when logging statistics.

```
function isRunningStandalone() {
    return (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches);
}
```

It would probably be a good idea for you to also record an event when the PWA is installed.